# The GNS3 Application no longer starts after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, python

The GNS3 Application no longer starts after upgrading Ubuntu to 20.04 LTS.

The output is the following:

```
v@V-PC:~$ gns3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f19c8132740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix this problem? I don't think it's a problem with GNS. It always was a stable application.

---

I tried do mentioned steps, but nothing changed as I see... What did I do wrong?

```
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
[sudo] password for vitek: 
 PPA for GNS3 and Supporting Packages. Please see  More info: Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]     
Get:3 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98,3 kB]  
Get:4 ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease [17,5 kB]       
Get:5 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [143 kB]
Get:6 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [66,0 kB]
Get:7 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [92,4 kB]
Get:8 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [29,3 kB]
Get:9 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [73,1 kB]
Get:10 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]     
Get:11 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [136 kB]
Get:12 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [532 B]
Get:13 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [87,2 kB]
Get:14 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [29,8 kB]
Get:15 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [33,2 kB]
Get:16 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18,7 kB]
Get:17 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [31,7 kB]
Get:18 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [9 880 B]
Get:19 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [15,0 kB]
Get:20 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B]
Fetched 1 095 kB in 1s (1 041 kB/s)        
Reading package lists... Done
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 ppa.launchpad.net/gns3/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Hit:5 security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease           
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ 
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ sudo apt install gns3-gui
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gns3-gui is already the newest version (2.2.8~eoan2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ 
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ gns3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fdfe480c740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ gns3-gui
gns3-gui: command not found
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ 
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ 
vitek@Vitek-PC:~$ gns3
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f11afefb740 (most recent call first):
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved by GNS3 re-install.

Answer (score 0):

> GNS3 not start after UBUNTU upgraded to 20.4 LTS

The Ubuntu 18.04 GNS3 version cannot be used in 20.04: It's missing the `qt4`, `python-qt4` packages as dependencies.

You can use the following PPA instead for 20.04 https://launchpad.net/~gns3/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gns3/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gns3-gui
```

`$ gns3`: The GNS3 window opens OK.